# What does Windows's "format X: /P:count" do?

Tags: windows, partitioning, format, secure-erase

What does `format X: /P:count` do in Windows? The documentation says:

```
/P:count          Zero every sector on the volume.  After that, the volume
                  will be overwritten "count" times using a different
                  random number each time.  If "count" is zero, no additional
                  overwrites are made after zeroing every sector.  This switch
                  is ignored when /Q is specified.
```

But I find this confusing. What "different random number" are they talking about?

Also, when I look at the raw partition with a hex editor after for example running `format X: /P:6` on some partition with drive letter X, all I see is that the partition contents have been erased, filled with zeros. There is nothing random about it.

Comment: I think it' wrong. Final pass writes zeros probably. Easy to test. Note that multiple passes are nonsense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your first question: either 0 or 1. It doesn't matter as long as it's just random nonsense, because it's meant to destroy what was originally in the sectors. Think monkey hitting random buttons on a typewriter . If you have a word like "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious" in your original data and it's replaced by "cdkjasghwudmqæeosgenakuetbrfkl", chances are that noone in the entire world will be able to restore your original word.

Answer to your second question: the Windows help item on the Format command is not entirely accurate regarding the /p switch. What it does is to fill random digits into a sector [count] times and THEN zero out the sector. Not the other way around. Again: it's not terribly relevant what number it is as long as any trace of the original data is removed. It could write 0 to the same sector every time, it would have the same effect.

I once had a very interesting conversation with a sysop about wiping hard drives, because I needed to make absolutely sure I was completely deleting data  from certain hard drives beyond any chance of recovery. He was employed with a huge company for whom data security was vital and thus he was an expert on data recovery and protection against it. He said that the magnetic plates inside brand new hard drives still have their magnetic capability completely intact and so magnetic "noise" and "echo" really isn't a problem, so simply using /p:0 (just writing a zero to every sector once) is quite enough in those cases. However, if the hard drive is aged a bit and/or has been used an awful lot, one should make sure to compensate for magnetic "noise" and "echo".

It's comparable to recording over a very old cassette tape (if you are as old as me, you are old enough to have tried this ): if you record enough times over it, it eventually starts to have echos from old recordings in the background. The same goes for hard drives of a certain age or if they have been used an awful lot, because they are magnetic, and at the end of the day, magnetism is not a very precise storage method, and it gets "worn".

So in conclusion: if a hard drive is old/worn, and you really need to make sure it's 100% wiped, you should up the [count] switch. I usually go with /p:2, which results in a total of three overwrites to each sector. In my view, that will always result in useless data, no matter how good the data recovery specialist is. However, it's always relative. The sysop also told me: places like NSA and CIA always overwrite sectors between 5-10 times and THEN they completely disassemble the disk and take a hammer to each plate, so I guess it's a matter of how badly you want data to be gone and stay gone.

Anyway, I hope this helps and that I have given a bit more insight to hard drive wiping.

Comment: Someone working at some company for which security is vital, does not make him a specialist on data recovery and data wiping. I regard such sources not valid. I have been contacted online by people claiming to be working at CIA, NSA or hard drive manufacturers and claiming they recover data after zero-fill, in similar discussions, but these are all claims without any evidence. I challenge anyone to send a zero filled drive to any lab and have them recover the data. My prediction is that the answer is 'we can not do that'.

Comment: Maybe so. I don't think the [count] option is there for the fun of it or to waste everybody's time, but on the other hand, I myself have considered 0 to be quite sufficient a number of times.

Comment: I don't know why the [count] option is there, but from security standpoint it's nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

Random data must be written into the sectors several times because someone with the diagnostic know-how and a clean-room can detect previous magnetic residue if the magnetic bits are overwritten only once.

Sure, YOU will see zeros if you look at the sectors.. but an data recovery expert might be able to read what you had there beforehand.

***Here is a specific reference from DOD material:***

A secure santize of rigid (removable and fixed) disk media as per the DOD clearing and sanitizing standard: DOD 5220.22-M .

The standard states that hard disk media is sanitized by overwriting with a character, then the character's complement, and then a random character. Note that the standard specifically states that this method is not suitable for TOP SECRET information.

TOP SECRET data sanatizing is only achievable by a Type 1 or 2 degauss of the disk, or by disintegrating, incinerating, pulverizing, shredding, or melting the disk. –

Actual reference: [is here](https://dami.army.pentagon.mil/site/IndustSec/docs/DoD%20522022-m.pdf)

This information would not exist of a simple "0 wipe" were enough to stop an expert from being able to retrieve information.

NOTE: in 1995, hard disks (HDD) work the same as they do now.

Comment: So what happens exactly then? What does the "random number" mean from the documentation?

Comment: @Ralph random, meaningless data. After all bits and bytes are binary numbers. You can see it this way: instead only zeroes, the additional pass(es) consists of ones at random spots.

Comment: I am not so sure. If that would be the case it would have said something like "After that, the volume will be overwritten "count" times using random data (randomly distributed zeros and ones)". Also it is not even true, as I see no random data; just zeros for count>0.

Comment: Believe what you will sir.  My answer is not wrong.  I hope you find the one you are looking for.

Comment: Since you seem quite sure, I'm inclined to believe that you're right. I just would like to understand why I'm seeing what I'm seeing. I made a 5MB NTFS partition and assigned drive letter Y, then ran format  Y: /P:8. Then I used a programme called wxHexEditor to look at the raw partition contents. It shows that mostly the partition consists of zeros, except for the leading part which I assume consists of the partition journal. Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: The final wipe is done with zeros.  Once upon a time, System Internals *used to* give away some of the source code (before MS bought it).  I read the "secure delete" source code which was very enlightening and detailed about *why* (and now probably part of the format command).  If you use the wayback machine, you can still see this source code from when it was free.. but you need to be able to read fairly low level c.

Comment: I'm slightly familiar with the sys-internals history. So the code stems from that guy who made that and it maybe ended up in format. That also explains maybe why the documentation quality doesn't seem so good. I mean, if what you say is correct, then the quoted help entry is even erroneous, because it clearly says that *after* the zero writing the random step is done. That together with the weird manner the random sweep is formulated seems like the work of an individual and not a big company. Anyway, thanks, and if anyone has more to enlighten us, please do! (Like a Wayback machine reference!)

Comment: Agreed! :) If anyone has something to add.. please add!!

Comment: A single zero fill is quite sufficient. I have yet to see a documented case where data was recovered after a zero fill. I only have examples of the contrary.

Comment: I personally don't disagree @JoepvanSteen but if you pull the source code I mention and read the notes, you will see that [Mark Russinovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Russinovich) disagrees.. or there is at lease some sort of USA federal standard.  I must assume that it is for a reason.

Comment: I know Mark Russinovich and I know his status. And yet, I dare go against the presumed authority he has on the matter. NIST says: "According to the 2014 NIST Special Publication 800-88 Rev. 1, Section 2.4 (p. 7): "For storage devices containing magnetic media, a single overwrite pass with a fixed pattern such as binary zeros typically hinders recovery of data even if state of the art laboratory techniques are applied to attempt to retrieve the data."[25] It recommends cryptographic erase as a more general mechanism."

Comment: I am not disagreeing with you @JoepvanSteen but NIST is a very small selection of US federal standard.  For instance, their criteria alone is not good enough for DOD.  It is funny that you mention NIST, I work directly with them every day as I am currently a Sr. Engineer on a FIPS validation team.  Nobody is disagreeing.  I saw notes in SDelete code about specific standards and thought I would mention it.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen .. answer updated with real information.

Comment: DOD 5220.22-M, 1995. I'd almost say, I rest my case.